# Insert variables into a table from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an assignment to create a table variable of origin city and country in separate columns from the production table.

The original production table got the [CITY-COUNTRY] in one column so the entities look like this [Paris-France] and I need to separate them into two separate columns but I'm having trouble putting this into a variable table.

So I created the table like this

```
DECLARE @FDep_City TABLE (City VARCHAR(50),
Country VARCHAR(50),
OriginalMade VARCHAR(50),)
```

and then I separated the columns like this, I just need a way to have this info in one variable table

```
SELECT RIGHT(@City, LEN(@City) - CHARINDEX('-', @City)) AS City2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` here:

```
INSERT INTO @FDep_City (City, Country, OriginalMade)
SELECT
    LEFT(Address, CHARINDEX('-', Address) - 1),
    RIGHT(Address, LEN(Address) - CHARINDEX('-', Address)),
    Address
FROM OriginalTable;
```

### Demo